# Using drush config import and update db in a rolling deployment (k8s) environment

Tags: drush

Disclaimer: complete Drupal newbie here. I'm the infrastructure guy in the team.

We are running various Drupal 8.9 instances on Kubernetes using a managed MariaDB outside k8s.

We build Docker containers for each instance on a build server using composer. Then, once deployed, a script initializes Drupal using a combination of `drush cim`, `drush cr`, `drush updb` and a few conditionals.

Kubernetes provides a rolling deployment so the current instance keeps running until the new container is up.
Now here's the issue I can't wrap my head around: the new and old instance both write to the same database. So `drush cim` from the new instance runs against the same DB as the live environment, possibly breaking the live instance.

I'm currently trying to catch this in my init script, but it proves to be non trivial. Ideas I came up with like cloning the db, doing the import there, testing if it works and then reimporting on the live instance appear overly complicated, Right now I do a dump before the `drush cim` so I can at least restore the instance if it fails but the site might still go down for a few minutes ... is there a Drupal way of doing this properly? Maybe a config import dry run or forcing drush cim to use a SQL transaction? Do you guys have any idas or input? Anything helps. Thank you!

Comment: May be this can help? https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2019/running-drupal-kubernetes-docker-production . Refer persistent database part.

Comment: Thanks, I know geerlingguy and stumbled upon this article as well. Unfortunately it does not go into detail in that regard but merely describes the challenges with persistent data